# Moving cells on UITableView with moveRowAtIndexPath

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a UITableView in which each cell has a switch. When the switch is turned on, I want the cell to move to the bottom of the tableView.

```
let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: sender.tag, inSection: 0)
let finalIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: tasks.count - 1, inSection: 0)

let task = tasks[indexPath.row]
tasks.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
tasks.append(task)
self.taskTableView.moveRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, toIndexPath: finalIndexPath)
```

When using the code above the first switch selection does exactly as I wanted, although after that pressing the switch on a cell causes the cell *below* it to move to the bottom. Any tips, ideas or help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to do with how your setting the .tag property.  If your using that to get the index then those will need to be updated every time you make a change and move things around.

Comment: You got it! Thanks so much. If anyone wants to know, I used a for loop to loop through all the cells and updating their tags after running the move cell block.

Comment: Hey, do you know how I could update the .tag property of the switch on a cell that isn't currently visible? Thanks.

Comment: If a cell isn't currently visible then it doesn't exist, tableviews only populate cells that are visible.  If your trying to make changes then u should add those changes to your data source.  I'm assuming in the tasks array there is an object with data associated for a cell.  Add something in there that lets u change its tag when populated through cellForRowAtIndexPath when it gets called